# Instagram has a dark mode on desktop now, so it possible to embed an Instagram post in dark mode?

Tags: html, instagram, embed

Instagram has a dark mode available on desktop which can be activated on the current session by adding `?theme=dark` to the URL, like so:

https://www.instagram.com/?theme=dark

I have a website with a black background, and currently the Instagram embed code embeds a white background which doesn't look too nice.

Is there any way to force the Instagram embed to switch to the dark theme? I tried adding that line to the URLs in the HTML code, but it didn't change it.

Comment: I wish somebody create an online service to embed Instagram Posts in different modes and styles, including Dark Mode, like they have on Twitter